# Stop Sub from running from another event without checking for a boolean

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have this code which controls an equipment I'm building. My main Sub sends several comands to the hardware, always waiting the necessary time to perform the action. The algorithm is something like:

```
Private Sub StartAuto()
    Send command1 to hardware and wait x seconds
    Send command2 to hardware and wait y seconds
    Send command3 to hardware and wait z seconds
    etc
End Sub
```

The thing is, I want to be able to stop the execution of this routine with a **Stop** button. So far I couldn't think or find any better method than checking a boolean between every command, which would be terrible:

```
Private Sub btStopAuto_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btStopAuto.Click
    keepRunning = false
End Sub
Private Sub StartAuto()
    keepRunning = True
    Send command1 to hardware and wait x seconds
    If (keepRunning = false)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Send command2 to hardware and wait y seconds
    If (keepRunning = false)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Send command3 to hardware and wait z seconds
    If (keepRunning = false)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    etc
End Sub
```

I thought about using `While` loops, but they will only validate after the whole procedure is done.

Essentialy what I need is something like

```
Private Sub btStopAuto_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btStopAuto.Click
    StartAuto.Exit
End Sub
```

Obviously this doesn't exist, any ideas on how it could be done? Right now, if I notice a problem during the procedure I have to abort the debugging, but that won't work outside development.

Thank you.

Comment: **Unfortunately, that is basically the correct way to do it!**  If possible, you could place the commands with their respective delays into some kind of List and then iterate over that.  This way you'd only have one check for the boolean inside the loop.  Realistically, though, this simply moves the changes you'd have to make to a different portion of the code.  Technically speaking you could move StartAuto() into a Thread and then kill it with Abort(), thus removing the need for a boolean, but that is **NOT** the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you called AutoStart() in another tread, you could then cancel the thread.

The boolean flag is the best/easiest way but the thread is an option.